# How to pack a Chrome extension on Mac OSX with commandline?

Tags: macos, command-line, google-chrome

I am trying to automate my Chrome extension building process on OSX 10.5.
I am unable to find a similar command for OSX like this for Windows

> chrome.exe --pack-extension=c:\myext
>   --pack-extension-key=c:\myext.pem

Is it even possible on OSX? As there is no mention of it in the [documentation](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/packaging.html).

Please guide me.

Thanks in advance.
-Parimal Das

Answer (score 15):

```
/Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome --pack-extension...
```

Comment: This works, but shell expansion is not supported so be sure to use the full path (not relative (e.g. ../ or ~/)). Also, there is no success/error messaging. My output stated "Breakpad disabled" but still worked when using the right paths. More info: http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=87085

Answer (score 3):

Use the [CRXMake](https://github.com/Constellation/crxmake) gem.

Have a great day.

Answer (score 1):

A complete example to run on the shell:

`"/Users/varr/Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome" --pack-extension="/Users/varr/Dropbox/Code/Projects/Bookmark Express/src"`

Things to note:

- Chrome will not display any output of success or failure but it will return an exit code
- Your shell (ex. oh-my-zsh) may display exit codes so you can have an idea there
- Chrome will generate two files, the `.crx` and a `.pem`

To automate this, I used [Geb](http://www.gebish.org/) (and [Groovy](http://groovy-lang.org/)). In `GebConfig.groovy`, I tried using:

```
def chromePath = "/Users/varr/Applications/Google Chrome Canary.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome Canary"
def packExtensionSwitch='--pack-extension="/Users/varr/Dropbox/Code/Projects/Bookmark Express/src"'

ProcessBuilder packExtension = new ProcessBuilder(chromePath, packExtensionSwitch)
Process process = packExtension.start()
```

But this returned an exit code 21 every time and no files were generated. I finalized my approach with:

```
def packageExtensionScript = '/Users/varr/package.sh'

ProcessBuilder packExtension = new ProcessBuilder(packageExtensionScript)
Process process = packExtension.start()
```

To finish it up, I made `package.sh` a one-line script with the command to run and it all worked!

Answer (score 1):

You can use [A node.js command line app for packing Google Chrome extensions](https://github.com/oncletom/crx) too. Enjoy!